# Any infinite sequence of points in a topological space having an open set such that no points enter the open set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm trying to find an example of a path connected topological space $X$ such that for any sequence in $X$, there is a nonempty open set in $X$ containing no point of the sequence.

The example I came up with was to let $X$ be any  set equipped with the discrete topology. Then for any sequence, let $U=\{x\in X : x\notin \{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\}$. Then $U$ is open and contains no points from the sequence. Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument does not work.

First of all, you need to argue that $U$ is *nonempty* - for this, you need $X$ to be uncountable (otherwise $\{x_i\}$ could enumerate all of the points in $X$, leaving nothing for $U$).

Far more importantly, *$X$ is not path connected*! No discrete topological space with more than one point is path connected. So this approach won't work.

---

Note that any space with a countable dense set is going to fail to be an example: letting $\{x_i\}$ enumerate the points in that set, we get a sequence which intersects every nonempty open set.

So we need a space which is "inherently uncountable". At the same time, it needs to be path connected - for simplicity, let's look for one that is "basically a line".

Do you know any spaces that look like a line, but "more uncountable"?

Comment: My first guess would be the real line, but since the sequence of rationals would intersect every open set that doesn't work?

Comment: @Crunch Yup, that example won't work. So how can you "stretch" the real line to fix it? (HINT: think about some uncountable sets you know . . .)